# Расположение полей в памяти при наследовании

Tags: c++, наследование, pod

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    float f;
};

struct B : A
{
    char c;
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли гарантия того, что `c` располагается в памяти строго за `f`. Причем, точно таким же образом, как если бы эти члены изначально находились в одной структуре?

Также мне интересно, если `B` не будет являться `POD` типом, измениться ли что-то в расположении `c` в памяти?

Comment: Вот как раз "изначально в одной структуре" ничего не гарантируется, даже скорее всего компилятор бы их переставил. UPDATE: Хм.. Что-о не хочет подтверждаться: https://ideone.com/69GsAq & https://ideone.com/WWDz8M

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "строго"?.  Что адрес f будет на sizeof(int) больше адреса i? Это возможно гарантировать, если класс объявить упакованным при помощи #pragma pack и подобного. И так лучше не делать, потому что отказ от выравнивания влияет на производительность.

Comment: @gdg, отказ от выравнивания не только влияет на производительность, но также привносит очень тонкую грань, которую легко переступить и получить неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 3):

Поля класса с одним уровнем доступа располагаются строго последовательно:

> **12.2 Class members [class.mem]**
>   18 Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 14) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (Clause 14).

Расположение базовых подъобъектов неспецифицировано:

> **13 Derived classes [class.derived]**
>   5 The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most derived object (6.6.2) is unspecified.

Однако для standard-layout классов адрес объекта обязательно совпадает с адресом первого поля и / или с адресом первого подъобъекта:

> **12.2 Class members [class.mem]**
>   25 If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first base class subobject (if any).

Из этого всего следует, что `с` в классе `B` не обязательно будет располагаться за `f` так как класс `B` не является standard-layout классом, а вот если бы оно было объявлено после `f` в классе `A`, то тогда было бы обязательно расположено строго после `f` и в памяти.

Comment: Вы внесли отсебятину, добавив "строго" в перевод стандарта. Порядок перечисления сохраняется, но компилятор, по своему желанию, может нывтыкать выравнивающие байты между полями, если это насильно не отключить при помощи #pragma pack и подобных директив.

Comment: @gbg Это вы вносите отсебятину, добавив "без выравнивающих байт" в "строго последовательно".

Comment: Я вкладываю в "строго" следующий смысл - что адрес f на sizeof(int) больше адреса i. А вы что имеете в виду?

Comment: Не совсем верно. Из этого следует совсем другое...

Answer (score 0):

Члены  класса(структуры) конструируются и распологаются по такому же порядку, по которому они были объявлены( порядок иниуиализации не имеет значения). Значит, в структуре `А`, как сказано в  `12.2 Class members [class.mem]`, приведенной   `user7860670`,  элементы обьекта будут распологаться строго по порядку:

```
обьект  A() -> | i | f |
```

Тут адрес `A()` совпадает с адресом `i` , как сказано в `12.2 Class members [class.mem] 25` .

Обьекты типа `В`,  будут иметь один подобьект базового класса  `А`, это значит, что на его основании  лежит объект `А()` +  у него еще есть член   `char c`, который расположится после обьекта `А()`.

```
 обьект  В() -> | A() | c |
```

Это значит, что `с`, в классе `В`, в данном случаи, **обязательно** будет распологаться после  `f`

```
 обьект  В() -> | i | f | c |
```

Но, если есть наиболее производный обьект (most derived object), например:

```
struct D {
    int m{};
};
struct most_derived : D, B {};
most_derived  md_obj;
```

который имеет  подобьект типа `А`, подобьект типа `В`(который в свою очередь имеет подобьект типа `А`)  и подобьект типа `D`
И вот тут : порядок расположения подобьектов (`D() и В()`), в  наиболее производном обьекте ( `md_obj` ) для базового класса  `А`, не определен,следовательно  в обьекте `md_obj` порядок следования `m` и `с`, не определено(в частности `&md_obj` будет совпадать  с `&m` или с `&i` ?... неизвестно) _  вот о чем  говорится в

> 13 Derived classes [class.derived] 5

.

**Вывод:** если `В` является не `POD`  типом, расположение `с` всеравно не изменится,  оно может изменится только в другом не `POD` типе _ таком, как `most_derived`