# Как обратится к полю конкретного прародителя из наследника?

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Вот код описывающий суть моей проблемы:

```
#include <iostream>

struct parent
{
    int quality = 1;
};

struct succesor : parent
{
    int quality = 2;
};

struct grandsuccesor : succesor
{
    int quality = 3;
};


int main()
{
    grandsuccesor example;
    std::cout << example.quality << std::endl << sizeof(example);
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
3
12
```

То есть поле `example.quality` выбирается из самого класса, а не родителя. Но как обратится конкретно, допустим, к полю parent quality? Ведь `sizeof(example) = 12`, а значит все таки выделяется 3 различных переменных. А как обратится к каждому из них?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::cout << example.parent::quality << '\n';
std::cout << example.succesor::quality << '\n';
```

А если написать `example.grandsuccesor::quality`, то это будет эквивалентно просто `example.quality`.

---

Есть еще вариант - скастовать класс в ссылку на родителя, и обратиться к полю:

```
static_cast<parent &>(example).quality
```

---

Методы так тоже можно вызывать.

Но у первого способа есть особенность - он игнорирует виртуальность методов. То есть если написать `x.Родитель::Метод()`, то вызовется именно метод родителя, даже если он виртуальный и был переопределен.

Comment: а  почему обязательно в ссылку? Можно ведь и  в тип, На объект это не влияет.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Тогда `parent` скопируется. В принципе работать будет, но это лишняя копия.

Comment: Для такого простого типа копирование даже эффективнее, нет?

Comment: Мне кажется со ссылкой в любом случае не должно быть медленнее, особенно если включить оптимизацию. И главное, не надо думать, какой перед тобой тип - быстро копируемый или нет...

Comment: только для получения данных базового класса, думаю вообще не стоит думать копировать или ссылаться. В целом, с вами согласен. Я лишь хотел, чтобы читающие ответ, случайно не думали, что можно получить только ссылку или  обращаться к полю только посредством ссылки...

Answer (score 1):

Можно обратиться путем частичного разыменования:

```
int main()
{
    grandsuccesor example;
    succesor *ptr_succesor = &example;
    parent *ptr_parent = &example;
    std::cout << example.quality << std::endl << ptr_succesor->quality << std::endl << ptr_parent->quality;
}
```

Comment: можете чуть чуть подробнее разъяснить почему это работает? почему вызов поля через указатель выдает именно нужное поле?

Comment: @Learpcs Это работает точно как каст в ссылку на родителя, только кода больше. *"почему ... выдает именно нужное поле"* Ну просто это так работает. Поля не "переопределяются" как виртуальные функции.

Comment: @Learpcs дело в том, что поля при наследовании располагаются строго последовательно. При использовании такого разыменования ограничивается область чтения.  Подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079060/Расположение-полей-в-памяти-при-наследовании)